# Amazon Cognito JWT Verify token error code 400 while downloading jwks json file

Tags: amazon-web-services, jwt, amazon-cognito

Currently I'm trying to verify the JWT Token getting from the user that's logged in.
Actually when I'm downloading the JWKS .json file from AWS Cognito (https://cognito-idp.{region}.amazonaws.com/{userPoolId}/.well-known/jwks.json) the console in the browser returns status code 400 bad request, but the contents in the file are visible in the browser.

Does anyone know a solution for this problem?

```
const getPemKey = async () => {
    const URL = `https://cognito-idp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/userpoolID.well-known/jwks.json.`

    try {
        const response = await fetch(URL);

        if(response !== 200) {
            throw new Error('Invalid URL')
        }

        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data)
        const keys = data;

        for (let index = 0; index < keys.length; index++) {
            const key = keys[index]
            const key_id = key.kid
            const modulus = key.n
            const exponent = key.e
            const key_type = key.ktl
            const jwk = { kty: key_type, n: modulus, e: exponent }
            const pem = jwkToPem(jwk)
            pems[key_id] = pem;
        }
        console.log(pems)
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        console.log('Sorry could not fetch pems')
    }

}
```

Comment: Hard to say without any code ...

Comment: Added code in post

Comment: `response` is an `object` so  `response !== 200` will always evaluate to true. You probably want to check `if (response.ok)` or `if (response.status !== 200)`. I'd suggest to use `response.ok` because it handles all 2xx status codes

Comment: I was having the same issue after over a year of working fine, no idea why. I was using 'request' to make the HTTP request. Changed to 'fetch' and it works fine now. Not helpful to you as you are already using fetch. Check your URL though, you missed a slash out after userpoolID.